# Conditionally terminate SAS

Tags: sas

I am trying to stop the processing of a SAS program if a certain condition has been met. I have a macro variable created and if that variable is > 0.5 then I want a hard stop of the program.

Current program looks like

```
data a1;
set Server.a2;
run;

%macro1(a1);

%macro2(_t1); /* _t1 generated from %macro1.

data _null_;
if %stopit(_t2) > 0.5 then `?????`; /* _t2 generated from %macro2.

run;

%macro3;

%macro4;
```

If `%macro(_t2) > 0.5`, I want to stop of whole program without running the rest (%macro3 and %macro4)

Comment: Just to clarify, are you running in batch mode or interactive mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I tend to always use `abort cancel;` (or `%abort cancel;`) as it offers flexibility when running in interactive mode and in batch mode.

Interactively it will just cancel the submitted code (but leave your session open).

In batch mode it will stop the entire job.

There are additional options as well.  You can find a full list in the documentation [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002475061.htm).

There's also the `endsas` command but I don't like that as it closes the current interactive session (and it's more difficult to execute conditionally).

Here's an example:

```
%let x = 1;

data _null_;
  if &x then abort cancel;
  put "This won't print";
run;

%put This won't print either;
```

The results in the log will show:

```
ERROR: Execution terminated by an ABORT CANCEL statement at line 4 column 14.
_ERROR_=1 _N_=1
```

Comment: For my case `abort abend` is better ? `abort cancel` only clears the current submitted program. But other subsequent submitted programs are not affected.

Comment: @rbet  Hmm, the only way you'd have anything submitted subsequently would be if you manually submitted more code an an interactive session.  Using abend will close your SAS session. I can't imagine you want that when you're running in interactive mode.  But test them both out and see what works best for your situation.

Answer (score 2):

Use following statement:

```
abort abend;
```

Comment: This answer is a good one, but it would be better with a bit more detail as to what that does - a link to the documentation and another sentence or two should be sufficient.